# Using Variable in lag function of dplyr - R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have written a function with variables. I am trying to compute lag for a given column of a dataframe. I am unable to do so. Following is my code snippet:

```
calculateLag <- function(df,lagCol,lagInterval){

  df <- df %>%
   group_by(grp = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(t)!=1))) %>%

   mutate(val_lag = lag(df[,lagCol],lagInterval)) %>%
   ungroup() %>%
   select(-grp)

   return(df)
}
```

I am getting error as :

```
 Error in `[.data.table`(df, , lagCol) : 
 j (the 2nd argument inside [...]) is a single symbol but column name 'lagCol' is not found. Perhaps you intended DT[,..lagCol] or DT[,lagCol,with=FALSE]. This difference to data.frame is deliberate and explained in FAQ 1.1.
```

Expected Result:

```
                   t         val   val_lag   val_lag2
 2005-01-17 17:30:00       14.3        NA         NA
 2005-01-17 18:30:00       14.0      14.3         NA
 2005-01-17 19:30:00       14.3      14.0       14.3
 2005-01-17 22:30:00       14.9        NA         NA
 2005-01-17 23:30:00       14.2      14.9         NA
 2005-01-18 00:30:00       14.1      14.2       14.9
```

Can someone help me in this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? Maybe `dput(head(df))`?

Comment: You are missing a bracket to close mutate_ command

Comment: I assume `t` is a time variable?

Comment: Yes @agenis, `t` is a time variable. I just want to select `df[,"col"]`, `"col"` is stored in variable `lagCol`.

Comment: Are you sure you want to reinvent dplyr's lead and lag functions?
http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/lead-lag.html

Comment: yeah it might be a XY problem. I would suggest first building a dataframe with a complete sequence of dates no?

Comment: @r.bot , It's not about re-inventing, it's about solving a problem at hand. And yes, got a solution for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*A reproducible example would be helpful*

Look at this example using `mtcars`

```
library(dplyr)
calculateLag <- function(df,lagCol,lagInterval){
  lagCol <- enquo(lagCol)    # need to quote
  df <- df %>%
         group_by(cyl) %>%
         mutate(val_lag = lag(!!lagCol, lagInterval)) %>%   # !! unquotes
         ungroup()
  return(df)
}

calculateLag(select(mtcars,cyl,gear), gear, 2)
```

See this [link](https://www.r-bloggers.com/non-standard-evaluation-and-standard-evaluation-in-dplyr/) about non-standard-evaluation

#### With your data

```
calculateLag <- function(df,lagCol,lagInterval){
    lagCol <- enquo(lagCol)
    df <- df %>%
            group_by(grp = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(t)!=1))) %>%
            mutate(val_lag = lag(!!lagCol, lagInterval)) %>%
            ungroup() %>%
            select(-grp)
    return(df)
}

calculateLag(df, val, 2)
```

#### Output with your data

```
                    t   val val_lag
1 2005-01-17 06:00:00  10.8      NA
2 2005-01-17 07:00:00  10.8      NA
3 2005-01-17 08:00:00  10.7    10.8
4 2005-01-17 09:00:00  10.6    10.8
5 2005-01-17 10:00:00  10.6    10.7
6 2005-01-17 11:00:00  10.7    10.6
```

Comment: This isn't working with my example. Here is reproducible content: `structure(list(t = structure(c(1105963200, 1105966800, 1105970400, 
1105974000, 1105977600, 1105981200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = ""), val= c(10.8, 10.8, 10.7, 10.6, 10.6, 
10.7)), .Names = c("t", "val"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")`

Comment: I intend to pass string if I get list of few columns, they will be stored as `character`. I want to pass "character" as parameter like `calculateLag(select(mtcars,cyl,gear), "gear", 2)`